# Switch to Modal window in robot framework

Tags: robotframework, modal-window

Can someone explain how to switch to modal window using robot framework.

Tried "Switch Window" and "Select Window" methods. Still showing elements are not interactable. Also tried the "Press Keys None TAB" method, but not efficiently working

It's a modal window inside the same page.

Comment: If you are using SeleniumLibrary, you can use `Alert Should Be Present` and `Handle Alert` keywords.